# How to publish Kotlin + JNI android library to Bintray?

Tags: android, kotlin, java-native-interface, bintray

I've been developing a library to use in my project, and while it is working locally, I would like to share it and use it as an external dependency.

How do I wrap my library so that built AAR contains both **.so* native library and generated **.java* classes (generated by Kotlin compiler) ? Because there are two-way interactions in my library: Kotlin external functions defined in C++, and some C++ code calling Kotlin classes and methods.

So, my questions are:

- How to correctly package Kotlin + JNI android library ?
- How to upload said package to Bintray so users (and myself) could use it as a dependency ?

*(Note: I've seen tutorials and examples, but they were either Kotlin/Android or Java/Jni/Android)*

Comment: Why would the Java/Jni/Android approach not work for Kotlin/Jni/Android? What difficulties did you encounter with those approaches?

Comment: @Botje I believe they were outdated or just didn't work in my case -- I had some Gradle undefined stuff errors (sorry, I can't really recall them). However, in this question, I want to find out _is_ there any differences between Kotlin and Java in such a task.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to package `.so` with your application, note that you can always put it inside `JAR` file. Then, you can unpack it, and load it using `System.load`.

You can find sample here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo031

**Note**

Remember that packaging `.so` inside application is a risky thing. As you deal with native code, you have to be 100% sure that all native dependencies are there. You have to pay attention to architecture as well.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this more ? What kind of gradle commands I should write in my _build.gradle_ to automate this ? (Example doesn't seem to be an android project)

Comment: I am not `gradle` expert :( For my samples I use `make` and explicit commands that are available in `JDK`. I suspect, for `gradle` you need to somehow mark `jar` as part of the process of `JAR` creation.